# Rails session lost after omniauth oauth redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, omniauth

We are using rails session to save user intention before using oauth (Linkedin). The idea here is to show different pages after Linkedin callback. The problem is we sometimes see session lost after Linkedin redirect callback, which causes errors on our side.

---

This is Rails session setup:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store 
  :cookie_store, 
  key: "_my_session_#{Rails.env}", 
  :secure => !ENV['NO_SSL'] && (Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?), 
  :expire_after => 100.years
```

This is how we set cookie before redirect to Linkedin auth page:

```
def social_login
  session[:intention] = 'login'
  redirect_to_provider(params[:provider], request.query_parameters)
end
```

Session contents after redirect:

```
{
  _csrf_token: nYlKmD/KAbj3hmWQ+cIethchxlHTOzUMjG/5y/fldLE=
  oauth: {"linkedin": {"callback_confirmed": true}}
  session_id: 4165617feee7f9a51148318d300291fc
}
```

Just in case: Rails 5.2.1, omiauth 1.8.1, Docker

Comment: Just a possible reason: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696204